# Arraylist not assigned with the value on app start from api query

Tags: java, android, arraylist, aws-amplify

I queried data from aws amplify GraphQL API and added the list of data to arraylist of same model class,when I'm printing the attributes of model on app start through Log.d I'm getting error, but when I put that Log.d in button.onClickListner there is no error and that expected outcome I got. I'm getting that outcome on button click but I need that on app start.My doubt is when app starts the arraylist already assigned with the query call but why I'm getting error when printing it & what happens when I put the Log.d in onClciklistner.If you are confused then look at at the below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<Todo> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dataQuery();//SECOND:with this call arraylist already have items
        Log.i("MyAmplifyApp","DESCRIPTION: "+ arrayList.get(0).getDescription());//THIRD:this line showing error that arraylist size is zero why?
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(v -> {
//FOURTH:when i put the above Log here there is no error and it is printing the attribute (arrayList.get(0).getDescription()) properly and how the arraylist getting the item on click
          });
}
    public void dataQuery(){
        Amplify.API.query(
                ModelQuery.list(Todo.class, Todo.NAME.contains("My first todo")),
                response -> {
                    for (Todo todo : response.getData()) {
                        arrayList.add(todo);//FIRST:arraylist already assigned with this
                    }
                },
                error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Query failure", error)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @ryan-m The duplicate that you posted indicates that the problem is with a method being asynchronous.  Which method call in the OP code is asynchronous?

Comment: @ScaryWombat `Amplify.API.query` - note the `response -> {` callback where the ArrayList is actually populated.

Comment: Tell me any solution for that if you know